# Model object not preserved when using hash for model in ember route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

**EDIT: I've set up an actual [repro of the issue on JSBIN](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11283)**

Been trying to resolve this for a while now and I'm clearly not understanding how the relationship between model and setupController works. I have a model which is returning a hash; the result of two find calls:

```
model(params) {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    course: this.store.find('course', params.course_id),
    topics: this.store.find('topic', { course_id: params.course_id })
  });
},
```

The first time setupController gets called, the value of `model` if as expected, a hash like `{ course: <Class>, topics: <Class> }`. Awesome, that's what I want.

However, the next time setupController gets called (for example, transition to another route and then press the back button in the browser), the `model` is now *just* the course `<Class>`:

```
setupController(controller, model) {
    // when first called model will be { course: <Class>, topics: <Class> }
    // next time entered, model will just be <Class> (just the value of "course" )
    // why is the model object not preserved?
   controller.set('model', model.course);
   controller.set('topics', model.topics);
}}
```

If I just make `model()` return a single resource, it's the same every time:

```
model(params) { return this.store.find('course', params.course_id); }
// now `model` will always be "course" in setupController
```

Why is the original model not preserved when using a hash result? Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're sending the model `color` when you're linking here:

`{{#link-to 'color' color}}{{color.name}}{{/link-to}}`

Because of that, the model hooks aren't run. If you change that to color.id, it'll work.

It's mentioned [here](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/templates/links/).

> In the above example, the model hook for PhotoRoute will run with
>   params.photo_id = 5. The model hook for CommentRoute won't run since
>   you supplied a model object for the comment segment. The comment's id
>   will populate the url according to CommentRoute's serialize hook.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at it, the original model will not be preserved because on setupController, you are calling controller.set('model', model.course). When it first loads, its called the `model(params {}` function appropriately, but on back button transitions and certain `{{link-to}}` calls, that isn't always the case.

In your setupController, try changing it to `controller.set('course', model.course);`, that way you aren't overwriting your model on execution as well and it will always be able to find it.

Comment: No luck because the next time setupController is called, "model" is equal to "model.course" from the first time. Could be a bug?

Comment: @typeoneerror - Perhaps? Try controller.set('model', model)?